# Unsuitable value for unary operand: number required.- Amazon elasticache cluster by terracode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am wiring the terraform script for elasticache, and there was not able to satisfy the one of the param value **transit_encryption_enabled**.. i am parsing the variable value is transit_encryption_enabled = true by xxx.tfvars file.

I got an error message when i did terraform plan.

│ Error: Invalid operand
│
│   on main.tf line 19, in module "elastic_cache_cluster":
│   19:   transit_encryption_enabled       = -var.transit_encryption_enabled
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.transit_encryption_enabled is true
│
│ Unsuitable value for unary operand: number required.

trying now to brought up the elasticache cluster with transit enabled with token.. need a solution for this.

Comment: Please share the code that you are using to deploy the elastic cache for a relative answer.

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo in your code? I see an unnecessary `-` there. It should be: `transit_encryption_enabled = var.transit_encryption_enabled`